# Credits and license in SVG images

Tags: svg

What is the correct method of adding author and license metadata information to SVG images? By hand and in Illustrator and Inkscape. Thanks.

Comment: I found this for you: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/metadata.html#metadataElementExample

Comment: Thanks! That shows how to do license information by hand, which is one part of my question.